# Replace n patterns in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Is there an easy way to fix this code:

```
title_1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').html();
title_2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').next().html();
title_3 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').next().next().html();

question = question.replace(/{title_1}/g, title_1);
question = question.replace(/{title_2}/g, title_2);
question = question.replace(/{title_3}/g, title_3);
```

So it isn't so dully (repeated) and can cover *n* occurences of `title_` pattern?

I'm a beginner Javascript developer and a complete regular expressions newbie (actually, they scare me! :|), so I'm unable to do this by myself. I've tried to [look](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7786000/1469208) for [an inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20694689/1469208) in [different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5262740/1469208) [languages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5318143/1469208), but failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function in the replace, to get the value depending on what you find:

```
question = question.replace(/{title_(\d+)}/g, $.proxy(function(x, m){
  return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq('+(m-1)+')').html();
}, this));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n3qrL/

Comment: `m` should be the second parameter.

Comment: @xdazz: Yes, you are correct. Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 2):

**[String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** could take a function as second parameter.

```
var $this = $(this);
question = question.replace(/\{title_(\d+)\}/g, function(match, n) {
  return $this.closest('tr').find('td').eq(n - 1).html();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rFPmR/)**

Try this , 
Generalized for getting all td tag's text value :

```
$("table").find("tr").each(function(){

 $(this).find("td").each(function(){
     alert($(this).html());
     var txt=$(this).html();
     //var pattern="/{"+txt+"}/g";
     //question = question.replace(pattern, txt);
 });
});
```

NB. In your question you have not mentioned the value for 'question' . please define value for 'question'

Comment: Yeap, you're right! I was always told to paste only _imporant_ parts of code, when asking questions in SE.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want to get the text content of the first three cells of a table row and use it to replace the content of a string, and that *this* is an element somewhere in the row. So you can do:

```
var n = 3;  // number of cells to get the text of
var textArray = [];
var tr = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
var reString;

for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
  reString = '{title_' + (i+1) + '}';
  question = question.replace(reString, tr.cells[i].textContent);
}
```

If you wish to avoid jQuery's *closest*, you can use a simple function like:

```
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
  do {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  } while (el.parentNode)
}
```

then:

```
var tr = upTo(this, 'tr');
```

Comment: Yeap, you're right! The only difference (as exposed in last question's paragraph) is, that I want this for _n_ cells of a table row, no for just the three first.